# How to check id name if contains some pattern?

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery and I am looping like:

```
$("span").each(function (index) {
    var idname = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#" + idname).click(function () {
        window.location.href = "http://" + $(this).attr('id') + "lin.gw";
    });

}); //end for click attachment to button
```

I would like to loop over the elements where `id` contains `*raid*`.  What is the syntax for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [attribute-contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/):

```
$("span[id*=raid]").click(function(){
    window.location.href = "http://"+ this.id +"lin.gw"; 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The nicest way to do this is using [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to remove elements you don't want:

```
$("span").filter(function() {
    if (this.id.toLowerCase().indexOf('raid') !== -1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}).click(function(){
    window.location.href="http://"+this.id+"lin.gw"; 
});
```

This uses `this.id` (far more efficient than `$(this).attr('id')`) and uses a single `click` call rather than using `each`, which is more legible and offers a slight performance increase.

Answer (score 0):

By 'like "*raid*"' I presume you mean that it contains "raid". The easiest way to do this is to test a regular expression: `/raid/.test(idname)`. This returns `true` if it's like "raid" and `false` if it's not.

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex for this. Below is a sample of regex mail matching. You can write your own regular expression and check if "idname" contains "raid".

`function IsValidEmail(email) {
                var filter = /^([\w-.]+)@(([[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.)|(([\w-]+.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(]?)$/;
                return filter.test(email);
            }`