# all checkboxes containing a string in a part of their id

Tags: jquery, foreach

I would like to go through all checkboxes on a page, that contain "_small" in their id.

how can I start a loop through all that elements?

Comment: possible duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123406/how-to-check-id-name-if-contains-some-pattern

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use:

```
$('input:checkbox[id*=_small]')
```

**Additional Notes:**

> Because :checkbox is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS
>   specification, queries using :checkbox cannot take advantage of the
>   performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll()
>   method. For better performance in modern browsers, use
>   [type="checkbox"] instead.

```
$('input[type=checkbox][id*=_small]')
```

So to loop through elements:

```
$('input[type=checkbox][id*=_small]').each(function(){
     // >>this<< refers to specific checkbox
});
```

Comment: if he wants to loop through them all he should use this selector with .each() function

Answer (score 7):

You can use "*=" selector:

```
$("[id*=_small]")
```